# How to find an array in an object of arrays

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, object, comparison

I have an array similar to this

```
 export const PRIVILEGES: privileges[] =   [
  {
    Role: ['admin','trainer','trainee','designer'],
    Home: true,
    UserManagment:  true,
    DefineTraining:true,
   AssignTraining:  true ,
    AssignedTraining:  true,
    PerformanceAnalysis:  true
  },
  {
    Role: ['admin','trainee'],
    Home: true,
    UserManagment:  true,
    DefineTraining:false,
   AssignTraining:  false ,
    AssignedTraining:  true,
    PerformanceAnalysis: true
  }]
```

and I have a Role defined as

```
Role=['admin','trainee']
```

***"I want to get the object of PRIVILEGES where Role matches PRIVILEGES.Role"***

I have tried

```
PRIVILEGES.find(x => x.Role == this.Role);
```

but this won't work because Role is an array and even though both x.Role and this.Role are same it returns a negative result.

Comment: Little bit rude this is really no duplicated question but w/e.
What you can do is use `let keys = Object.keys(PRIVILEGES);
for (let PRIVILEGE in keys) { let object = PRIVILEGE.find(x => x.Role == this.Role); }` hope this helps. But check Maksyms responce it's better.

Comment: try `PRIVILEGES.filter(x => x.Role.indexOf(this.Role) > -1);`
find will return only first match, filter will return an array of all matches

Comment: Above comments assume that `this.Role` is a string, but it is an array.  The question is therefore asking how to compare two arrays as equal.  So it is a duplicate question and the linked question has many useful answers.  If you think this is not the case and can explain why, I'd be happy to reopen the question.

Comment: if `this.Role` is an array, then you need to write your own compare function. It will be formatted badly, can't post an answer here. `compareArrays(arr1: Array<string>, arr2: Array<string>): boolean { 
  if (arr1.length !== arr2.length) { return false; }   
  let match: boolean = true;
  for (let i = 0; i < arr1.length) {
     if (arr1[i] === arr2[i]) { return }
     match = false;
  } 
  return match;
}`